# how to align view at the bottom of the screen but also below other view in relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-relativelayout

I want imageView to be at the bottom of the screen always but I also want it to be below the LinearLayou view so that, they don't overlap each other and the image can change its size as per screen.

here is what I'm doing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_color"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/main_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/main_padding"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/main_padding"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".welcomeActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_welcome"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/great_vibes"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/actionbar_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/who_am_i"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_white"
        android:textSize="44sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/lisearLayout_welcome"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_welcome"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            style="@style/MyCardView"
            app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:id="@+id/customerButton"
            android:layout_height="200dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:text="@string/customer"
                    android:textSize="44sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/great_vibes"
                    android:textColor="@color/button_color_black1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            style="@style/MyCardView"
            app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:id="@+id/employButton"
            android:layout_height="200dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:text="@string/employ"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/great_vibes"
                    android:textSize="44sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/button_color_black1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/image_welcome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lisearLayout_welcome"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_french_fries"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

see this yellow gap between the bottom and the image, that's what I don't want.

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I added in the top `RelativeLayout` the attribute `alignPatentBottom="true"` now your pommes frites should be on the bottom. :) In my emulator everything works fine. Glad to have some feedback if it works?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_color"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/main_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/main_padding"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/main_padding"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".welcomeActivity"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_welcome"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/great_vibes"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/actionbar_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/who_am_i"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_white"
        android:textSize="44sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/lisearLayout_welcome"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_welcome"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            style="@style/MyCardView"
            app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:id="@+id/customerButton"
            android:layout_height="200dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:text="@string/customer"
                    android:textSize="44sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/great_vibes"
                    android:textColor="@color/button_color_black1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            style="@style/MyCardView"
            app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:id="@+id/employButton"
            android:layout_height="200dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:text="@string/employ"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/great_vibes"
                    android:textSize="44sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/button_color_black1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_welcome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lisearLayout_welcome"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_french_fries" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: na it doesn't work, there is still that gap

Answer (score 1):

Remove `android:layout_below="@+id/lisearLayout_welcome"` in the `ImageView` and add  `android:layout_above="@id/image_welcome"` to the `LinearLayout`.
In this way you are assigning the available space to the `LinearLayout`, instead in your code you are assigning the available space to the `ImageView`.

Use something like:

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <TextView/>
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_above="@id/image_welcome"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_welcome">

       <!-- ... -->

  </LinearLayout>

  <ImageView
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/image_welcome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/..."
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Apply different orientation in the LinearLayout using `vertical` in portrait mode, and `horizontal` in landscape mode.

[image][image]

Comment: i don't want views to scroll , isn't there any other way

Comment: @TehleelMir Yes, it depends by what you want to achieve. For example a different layout with the card side by side?

Comment: yes, i want all views to be visible and without overlapping

Comment: @TehleelMir Just use the same layout reported in the answer and change the orientation of the LinearLayout (vertical in portrait mode, and horizontal in landscape mode)